What is an intercepting route in Next.js?
After reading the official documentation, I still didn't understand Next.js intercepting routes.
Given:

My questions:

When we navigate to /photo/id1, do both page.js files get rendered?
When we navigate to /feed/photo/id1, do both page.js files get rendered?
Do both files get rendered if we don't use a parallel route?
Will we ever need to intercept routes without using parallel routes?
Why can't we just conditionally render the modal within /photo/[id]/page.js, using URL '? parameters' and importing a template perhaps?
Are we supposed to specify the layout of both page.js files in layout.js?

A StackBlitz experiment can be found here.
